# Event handling in Go using channels

Tags: go, goroutine

I have written an SDK that encapsulates a bunch of logic and functionality.

Typically, I would use event listeners/callbacks to provide feedback to the application using the SDK, but that is not idiomatic in Go.

It is my understanding that channels and goroutines fill the void of callbacks but what is a way to implement this?

Say for example, my SDK has a number of events that I want to notify the main application about. Would I use one channel based on an `Event` struct. This `Event` would contain a `_type` field which specifies the event type, then a `data` field of type `interface{}` similar to `Object` in Java. The receiver would then check the type and cast the data accordingly.

Either the above approach or one channel for event then the app listens for whatever channels it is concerned with.

For the record I prefer the former approach but unsure about it's implementation.

Has anybody achieve this before and how did you implement?

Comment: There's nothing unidiomatic about callbacks in Go.  Go has first-class support for functional programming for a reason.  An enormous number of even the standard libraries use callbacks (example, the entire HTTP server implementation is based on handler callbacks).  Channels are awesome, but there's no reason they need to be used to the _exclusion_ of functional programming.

Comment: Because an `interface{}` contains a type and value, there's no need for the `Event` type.  The app can type switch or type assert on the `interface{}` values.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my https://github.com/tideland/gocells. It's a library for event driven applications. Here so called cells are started with behaviors responsible to process the events, these cells are connected.

Maybe you can use it or get some inspiration.